# How to determine if a hyphen (-) exists inside a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, string-searching

In a `CASE` expression, I'm trying to search inside a text column to identify a hyphen (-):

```
CASE 
     WHEN SUBSTRING(al.ALT_ADDRESS,1,1) IN('1','5','7') 
      AND al.NEW_ADDRESS CONTAINS '-' 
     THEN CONCAT(al.ALT_ADDRESS,al.NEW_ADDRESS)
```

The hyphen can be located anywhere in the column, and so I just need to know if it exists, regardless of where it actually is in the column.

I'm currently using the exact same code that [@Josh provided](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/238717/79999) (`LIKE '%-%'`), but it doesn't work, because it doesn't return the correct data for several specific instances where I know that it "should" be. The exact text in `ALT_ADDRESS` is: "2754 Churchill Circle". The exact text in `NEW_ADDRESS` is: "O-89421". However, the results that are returned, does not include the `NEW_ADDRESS` (O-89421).

I have confirmed that dash in `NEW_ADDRESS` really matches the dash I'm using the search (ASCII 45).

Comment: `'2754 Churchill Circle` doesn't meet the `SUBSTRING(al.ALT_ADDRESS,1,1) IN ('1', '5', '7')` criteria, since the substring is `'2'`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An alternative approach to the existing answer is to use the CHARINDEX() function which returns the position of the specified string if exists, otherwise 0.

```
select charindex('-','kevin-')
```

Will return 6, because the hyphen is located in the sixth position of the string, compared with

```
select charindex('-','kevin')
```

returns 0 because the '-' is not present in the string.

---

Per [John Eisbrener's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39083/john-eisbrener) suggestion, [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is also an option, and it allows for wildcards - which may prove beneficial in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 14):

You didn't mention why the code you provided doesn't work.  `CONTAINS` is for use with SQL Server's full text search feature.  If you're not using this, then you need to use a `LIKE` clause with wildcards:

```
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(al.ALT_ADDRESS,1,1) IN('1','5','7') AND al.NEW_ADDRESS LIKE '%-%' 
THEN CONCAT(al.ALT_ADDRESS,al.NEW_ADDRESS)
```

Even if you are using full text search, the matching behavior with dashes can be [unexpected](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/200043/prb-dashes-ignored-in-search-with-sql-full-text-and-msidxs-queries) and Microsoft recommends using `LIKE` instead.

---

You might double check that the character is really a hyphen, something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    ASCII('-') as RealHypen,
    ASCII(SUBSTRING(NEW_ADDRESS, 1, 1))
FROM YourTable
WHERE ALT_ADDRESS = '2754 Churchill Circle';
```

---

As an aside, the `LIKE` expression above is not able to make use of the seeking abilities of a b-tree index in SQL Server, so performance may suffer on large tables if a large scanning operation is required. The best way to mitigate that (should it apply to you or others in a similar situation) depends heavily on context, but in general the main alternatives are:

- Indexing a computed column that evaluates the search condition
- Using triggers to persist the search result in advance
- Use an external tool that's more suited to searching text (Elasticsearch is popular)
- Use [n-grams](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search) (typically for substrings of 3 characters or more)
- Use Full Text Search (this won't help with wildcards per se, or this specific case, but can work for word-based searching).

If you are interested in exploring the performance aspect, please ask a follow up question.

Answer (score 2):

## `LIKE '%-%'`

> I'm currently using the exact same code that @Josh provided (`LIKE '%-%'`), but it doesn't work, because it doesn't return the correct data for several specific instances where I know that it "should" be. The exact text in `ALT_ADDRESS` is: "2754 Churchill Circle". The exact text in `NEW_ADDRESS` is: "O-89421". However, **the results that are returned, does not include the NEW_ADDRESS (O-89421).**

I don't get this problem at all,

```
SELECT new_address
FROM ( VALUES
  ('O-89421')
) AS t(new_address)
WHERE new_address LIKE '%-%';
```

[Seems to work for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a5a51a020fec0d727f202622a51844c9)